# Dismissing dialog with Escape key with nested navigator

Tags: flutter, flutter-macos-2.0.0-stable

I'm writing a Flutter app targeted towards macOS and want to be able to show a modal dialog that allows navigation within that dialog (somewhat like a sequence of onboarding screens).

In order to facilitate the navigation within the dialog, I need to wrap my widgets in a navigator of some sort. See the following (simplified) code:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Dialog(
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      child: Navigator(
        onGenerateRoute: (_) => MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const Center(child: Text('hi there'))
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Now this works perfectly - except for dismissal. I can dismiss the dialog by tapping in the barrier area (which is good), however, pressing ESC on the keyboard doesn't dismiss the dialog.

If I just embed the child directly (without the navigator), pressing ESC dismisses the dialog perfectly. But for some reason, it looks like `Navigator` is swallowing the ESC key. I've also tried using `MaterialApp` as the navigator and it also eats the ESC key.

Any theories on how I can get the navigator to let me dismiss the dialog using the ESC key? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [RawKeyboardListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html) to listen to keypresses, and pop when an ESC event fired.

<s>Old response that didn't work: Try wrapping the widget inside the page route (in this case, the `Center`) with a `WillPopScope`. You should be able to receive the ESC event on the `onWillPop` callback before the inner `Navigator` receives it, then you can call `pop` on the outer `Navigator` to dismiss the dialog.</s>

Comment: That's a neat idea, but sadly `onWillPop()` doesn't get called (either when you press ESC or if the dialog gets dismissed by clicking on the barrier)

Comment: One other idea is to use a RawKeyboardListener to listen to keypresses, and pop when an ESC event fired.